# Utility class with method implementation in sub classes

Tags: java

I'm creating a utility class in java to integrate with Salesforce API. This class will typically be like

```
public final class SalesforceApi {

     public static void searchUser(){
     }

     public static void createUser(){
     }

     public static void searchCampaign(){
     }

     public static void createCampaign(){
     }

     ..........
}
```

I've ended up with multiple methods in this class. I would want to split it in sub classes like one for user related methods, other for campaign ones and so on. However, I want to be able to call all these methods on the parent class like `SalesforceApi.searchUser`.

How do I implement it?

Comment: Do they have to be static methods?

Comment: What I understand you mean by "split it in sub classes" and "call all these methods on the parent class like ..." seem like a conflict. Would it also help to do the implementations of the methods in different files, while they together are only one class?

Comment: Then split them up and inherit from `SalesforceApi`. What's the actual problem?

Comment: [Is it mandatory utility class should be final and private constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32375149/is-it-mandatory-utility-class-should-be-final-and-private-constructor)

Comment: Rather than a "superclass", maybe a facade class would be a better fit for your problem.

Comment: @Yunnosch yes, I just want it split in different files. How do I do that?